# Passing email @RequestMapping in Spring

Tags: spring, scala

I am passing the following PUT ( X.XXXXX.com/AAAA/BBBBB/CCCC/XXXXXX/employees/admin/uchei.ca@gmail.com ) to a REST service of the following request mapping :

```
 @RequestMapping(
    value = Array("/employees/{organizationIdentifier}/{emailString}"),
    method = Array(RequestMethod.PUT)
  )
```

Unfortunately, I receive a 405 error. I have tried

1. `/{emailString:.*}`
2. `/{emailString:.+}`
3. `/{emailString}/`
4. `/{emailString:^[a-zA-Z0-9\.!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$}`

Without any luck. Please advise on how to construct a valid regular expression or some other trick to get the above email to be passed without 405.

Comment: try this URL https://www.X.XXXXX.com/AAAA/BBBBB/CCCC/XXXXXX/employees/admin/uchei.ca%40gmail.com

Comment: I would like to parse out the email string at the end. Do I have to make changes to {emailString} ?

Comment: You cannot send a `@` you need to encode the URL so that any "weird" characters get properly encoded.

Comment: The URL that i put was encoded so try it

Comment: I edited the URL in the browser with %40 (@) and clicked on send, I still received a 405 from my backend.

Answer (score 0):

According to the single-responsibility principle, I wouldn't expect the proxy to validate email.

What is a proper email. If you decide to validate email at any time you'll have to answer yourself: what is a valid email. Is it a `String` which matches certain `regex` or a `String` which matches certain regex and has a valid domain. Or maybe it must have been used in your application at the registration, confirmed and already be stored in a database? In my opinion the last one.

If I were you, I would do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = Array("/employees/{organizationIdentifier}/{whatever}"),
    method = Array(RequestMethod.PUT)
)
```

I assume, that this email is a primary key in some table in your database.

Now in your `service-layer` you should start with querying the db with that email and checking if the returned entity is null or not. If it's not, it was a valid email, which was already verified somehow in your application.

You can also `@RequestParam`s and request param `idType`. If it's set to `email` do one thing, otherwise something else.